# App Center real device build error No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to build my app using App Center on a real device in release mode. I have chosen the right provision and the right certificate. Got this error `No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile` in App Center build output. How to solve this situation? https://prnt.sc/oq4cee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking [Code signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/xamarin/ios/#38-code-signing) with provision and certificate.

A successful device build will produce an ipa file. In order to install the build on a device, it needs to be signed with a valid provisioning profile and certificate. To sign the builds produced from a branch, enable code signing in the configuration pane and upload a [provisioning profile (.mobileprovision) and a valid certificate (.p12)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/uploading-signing-files), along with the password for the certificate. You can read more about code signing and device provisioning of Xamarin iOS apps in the [Xamarin official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/).

And Note:

> App Center does not currently support signing app extensions for Xamarin apps.